# Negative Lookahead for Regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

What is the difference between:

```
^(?!.*baa)[abc]*$
```

and

```
^(?!baa)[abc]*$
```

What is the role of that `.*`. I know it means any character 0 or more times but why does the second one capture strings like `cccaabaa` which should be discarded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between them is:

1. `^(?!.*baa)` requires that `baa` not be *anywhere* in the input
2. `^(?!baa)` requires that `baa` not be at *the start* of the input

The `.*` allows anything to be between start `^` and `baa`.

Comment: thanks. following this reasoning why don't we need to add `.*` after so that we can say this is not add the end of the input, like in `^(?!.*baa*.)[abc]*$`

Comment: @ocram yes - `.*` after `baa` makes no difference. If you wanted to prevent `baa` anywhere *except* the end used `^(?!.*baa.)`, which requires there to be (at least) one more character after `baa`

Answer (score 0):

> ^(?!.*baa)[abc]*$ - Starts from current position(here beginning due to
>   ^), consumes the whole string and then backtracks to find if there is
>   no `baa` anywhere in string. Now the position from which match of lookahead started(here beginning) check
>   whatever follows is combiantion of `a`, `b` and `c`

[image]

> ^(?!baa)[abc]*$ - Starts from current position(here beginning due to
>   ^) to check what follows
>   is not `baa`. `baa` can be anywhere but not in starting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`(?!  )` is a negative lookahead : it specifies a group that can't match.

In `^(?!baa)[abc]*$`, you are looking for a string which doesn't start with "baa" and have only characters in a b or c : `cccaabaa` match : it doesn't start with "baa".

In `^(?!.*baa)[abc]*$`, you are looking for a string which doesn't start with anything following by baa, and have only characters from a b or c : `cccaabaa` doesn't match because it starts with "cccaa following by baa"